# How to handle the quadratic constraint $x y \leq z$?

Tags: optimization, constraints

I have a quadratic constraint of the form

$$ x_1 x_2 \leq x_3 $$

where $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$. The objective is linear, and all other constraints are linear, too. I know that I can transform the product as

$$ y_1=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2) $$

$$ y_2=\frac{1}{2}(x_1−x_2) $$

$$ y_1^2−y_2^2\leq x_3 $$

But when it comes to the last constraint, it is not convex (matrix is not PSD), and thus not suitable for commercial solvers like CPLEX and Gurobi (as far as I know). Moreover, they are not conic quadratic representable. At least I don't know how to reformulate them, or to find a suitable approximation ("good for practical purposes"). Now, my question.

Is there an efficient (to some degree) approach to deal with these kind of constraints?

I am asking this because they look quite simple and the constraint expressions are the difference of convex functions $ y_1^2−(y_2^2+x_3) $ (the sum of two convex functions on different domains is convex).

Maybe some relaxation technique has been proven to be useful? Convexification? In other words, how to circumvent this?

Comment: I know it is not convex. But what to do with it?

Comment: Use a general purpose nonlinear optimizer which can accept non-convex nonlinear constraints. If we saw your entire optimization problem, maybe there could be some more specific suggestions.

Comment: The whole program is quite simple. Linear objective, linear constraints, and these bilinear constraints. That's all. If you want, I can edit my post, but I guess that you get the picture.

Comment: Also, I would like to stay out from the general purpose nonlinear solvers. Are there any good relaxation techniques (or convexification) that would give a decent approximation, i.e. the upper bound (if the objective it the maximization)?

Comment: I would consider the case in which the product constraint is tight, and use the equality $x_1 x_2 = x_3$ to eliminate one variable from the problem.

Comment: @hardmath If I understand, you are saying to solve this problem $ \min x_3 - x_1 x_2 $ under all other linear constraints with some heuristic (because the new problem is still non-convex), and then to eliminate one variable using the equality expression?

Comment: That's more elaborate than what I was thinking, but that is perhaps better.  I was just thinking that if the constraint is not tight (equality), then you can drop it and solve the remaining linear program (which I'm sure you already did).

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I already tried with the so called lifting to higher dimension $ x_{12} \leq x_3 $ and $ x_{12} = x_1 x_2 $. Then, the later equation could be dropped and we have a relaxation (I forgot to mention that all variables are positive and bounded, sorry). But I am not satisfied with the results. :/ Do you know how to strengthen this relaxation (except the fore mentioned approach)?

Comment: You convince me that the problem is tractable, but without the actual details I'm not able to actually produce the solution.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Sorry, I was busy these two days, I didn't even had a possibility to think about this problem. Well, the problem emerged when I was analyzing one location problem. So, the question was mainly theoretical. I am aware that the BARON could solve this if the dimension is not big. But for some instances that I am interested, the number of variables used in the quadratic constraints is in thousands.

Comment: I just received a new hint, which is quite good. Just attack those bilinear constraints with the logarithm. Exponential function has a good conic quadratic approximation for practical purposes. Therefore, this topic can be closed. :) Thanks to both of you, because from you I received some quite interesting ideas that could be helpful in some other occasions.

Comment: Are you referring to slavko's answer at https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/14687/approach-to-resolve-the-issue-with-a-non-linear-constraint-xy-z , which is the same as the given answer below by you? You should give "credit" to that answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is the Slavko's answer for OR-Exchange. But because that is an another forum, maybe a competing one, I did not want to put a link to it, immediately. I don't know how moderators would react. Maybe a little bit immature from me, but on different occasions on some different forums, moderators didn't want links to other competing sites. That's why I wrote I got the hint. :) On the other hand, I already told Slavko to convert its comment to an answer, so that I can accept it. :) If it is OK, I can edit the answer. Please, don't mind about that.

Comment: I think both forums would say that you shouldn't cross-post at the same time, and if you do, you should provide a link to any other posting on the same or similar question.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone I understand. But when it comes to the cross-posting, I was a little bit nervous, because on OR-Exchange, where I first posted the question, I saw some pretty weird posts (quite inappropriate topic, believe me). I have reported the users, of course, but somehow I worried if the things were working right on OR-Exchange. One more time, thank you for your tutoring. It won't happen again. :)

Comment: Some OR-Exchange moderators are on vacation, so SPAM is not being deleted as quickly as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only relevant part of your problem, you can write this as a semidefinite program. Since $x_1, x_2$ do not appear individually you can treat it as a square of a positive number then your problem is the feasibility of

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
x_3 & y  &  \\ 
y & 1 &   \\
&& y \\
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0
$$
where $y = \sqrt{x_1x_2}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, they do not appear individually in the constraints, but what if they appear in linear objective? My first thought was to lift the program into a higher dimension space, too (your approach is better, BTW). Then I saw that I could use reformulation-linearisation techniques (RLT) to strengthen the relaxation. But somehow, to me, it just looks like one can do much more. Like there is a trick that I can't see. Maybe my hunch is wrong about this (I am not an expert), but I had to ask.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks you are dealing with a standard Geometric Program (GP) which can be handled easily by commercial solvers (see e.g. https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dgp/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I got a new hint: https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/14687/approach-to-resolve-the-issue-with-a-non-linear-constraint-xy-z.

The bi-linear constraints can be attacked with the logarithm function. Therefore, we can introduce new variables $ z_i = \ln(x_i) $ and our constraints will become

$ z_1 + z_2 \leq z_3 $.

Of course, we have to include the additional constraints, too. Particularly, those that are representing the connection of $ z_i $ and $ x_i $

$ \exp(z_i) = x_i $.

But the exponential function is conic quadratic representable for practical purposes.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone Yes, of course, I was thinking about the inequality. Thanks for the note. :)